# Datavalidation in silverlight with wcf service reference class

Tags: silverlight-4.0, data-annotations, wcfserviceclient

HI,
Am using **wcf service** with **silverlight** and my datacontract class is exposed in the reference file and am binding a collection of class type to datagrid and while clicking a particular row for editing the entire row data will be binded to a dataform and there i have to validate the fields and here am using a **IDataErrorInfo** interface to validte,Here in service reference file the class is a partial class and created a new cs file with same namespace of the servicefile and class name then implemented the **IDataErrorInfo** interface properties

> public string this[string
>   columnName]{}

in the scope i worte the validation .But it is not working can anyone help for this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data annotations like RequiredAttribute and DisplayAttribute etc do not propagated to the generated client side files when using Silverlight 4 and WCF.
This is one solution for the problem...
Create a class library with a model (Model.dll)
sample

---

```
public partial class Person: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{ 
    private Guid IDField; 

    private string NameField; 

    private string LastNameField; 

    private int AgeField; 

    private string EmailField; 

    /// <summary> 
    /// ID of an Object 
    /// </summary>         
    public Guid ID 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return IDField; 
        } 
        set 
        { 
            if (value != IDField) 
            { 
                Validator.ValidateProperty(value, new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "ID" }); 
                IDField = value; 
                OnPropertyChanged("ID"); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    /// <summary> 
    /// Name of a person 
    /// </summary> 
    [Required]         
    public string Name 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return NameField; 
        } 
        set 
        { 
            if (value != NameField) 
            { 
                Validator.ValidateProperty(value, new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "Name" }); 
                NameField = value; 
                OnPropertyChanged("Name"); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    /// <summary> 
    /// LastName of a person 
    /// </summary> 
    [Required] 
    public string LastName 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return LastNameField; 
        } 
        set 
        { 
            if (value != LastNameField) 
            { 
                Validator.ValidateProperty(value, new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "LastName" }); 
                LastNameField = value; 
                OnPropertyChanged("LastName"); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    /// <summary> 
    /// Age of a person 
    /// </summary> 
    [Range(0,120)] 
    //[Required] 
    public int Age 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return AgeField; 
        } 
        set 
        { 
            if (value != AgeField) 
            { 
                Validator.ValidateProperty(value, new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "Age" }); 
                AgeField = value; 
                OnPropertyChanged("Age"); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    [RegularBLOCKED EXPRESSION] 
    public string Email 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return EmailField; 
        } 
        set 
        { 
            if (value != EmailField) 
            { 
                Validator.ValidateProperty(value, new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "Email" }); 
                EmailField = value; 
                OnPropertyChanged("Email"); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 

    /// <summary> 
    /// Raises a property changed notification for the specified property name. 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="propName">The name of the property that changed.</param> 
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propName) 
    { 
        if (PropertyChanged != null) 
        { 
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName)); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

---

In a services project reference this class library
a sample of services could be ...

```
[ServiceContract] 
    public interface IPersonService 
    { 
        [OperationContract] 
        List<Person> GetPersons(); 

        [OperationContract] 
        Person GetPersonByID(Guid ID); 

        [OperationContract] 
        void EditPerson(Person PersonField);         

    } 


///////////////// 



public class PersonService : IPersonService 
    { 
        private List<Person> Persons; 

        public PersonService() 
        { 
            Persons = new List<Person>(); 
            Persons.Add(new Person { ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Albert", LastName = "Pujols" , Age = 31, Email = "albert-p@mlb.com" }); 
            Persons.Add(new Person { ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Alex", LastName = "Rodriguez", Age = 36, Email = "alex-r@mlb.com" }); 
            Persons.Add(new Person { ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Evan", LastName = "Longoria", Age = 25, Email = "evan-l@mlb.com" }); 
            Persons.Add(new Person { ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Joey", LastName = "Votto", Age = 25, Email = "joey-v@mlb.com" }); 
            Persons.Add(new Person { ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Miguel", LastName = "Cabrera", Age = 27, Email = "miguel-c@mlb.com" }); 
            Persons.Add(new Person { ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Kendry", LastName = "Morales", Age = 26, Email = "kendry-m@mlb.com" }); 
            Persons.Add(new Person { ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Alexei", LastName = "Ramirez", Age = 28, Email = "miguel-c@mlb.com" }); 
        } 


        public List<Person> GetPersons() 
        { 
            return Persons; 
        } 

        public Person GetPersonByID(Guid ID) 
        { 
            return (from sel in Persons where sel.ID == ID select sel).First(); 
        } 

        public void EditPerson(Person PersonField) 
        { 
            Person Person = (from sel in Persons where sel.ID == PersonField.ID select sel).First(); 
            Person = PersonField; 
        }        

    }
```

Create a silverlight class library (SL.Model.dll) (this library have the sample model created in Model.dll)
in this class library add existing Item as link and add the model item that have Model.dll
in Silverlight Application reference the SL.Model.dll
when the services reference is create view that reuse types is cheked (It is deafault option)
sample of page ... 
xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="SampleApp.MainPage" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
             xmlns:dataInput="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data.Input" 
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400" xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"> 

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White"> 
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
            <ColumnDefinition Width="55*" /> 
            <ColumnDefinition Width="45*" /> 
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
        <sdk:DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" Grid.Column="0" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionChanged="dataGrid1_SelectionChanged" FontSize="12"> 
            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns> 
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn CanUserSort="True" Binding="{Binding ID}" Visibility="Collapsed" /> 
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn CanUserSort="True" Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" Width="100" /> 
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn CanUserSort="True" Binding="{Binding LastName}" Header="LastName" Width="100" />                 
            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns> 
        </sdk:DataGrid> 
        <Grid Grid.Column="1"> 
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40*" /> 
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" /> 
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" /> 
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
            <Grid.RowDefinitions> 
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/> 
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/> 
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/> 
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/> 
                <RowDefinition Height="150"/> 
            </Grid.RowDefinitions> 
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Name" Grid.Row="0" Margin="4" /> 
            <TextBox x:Name="Name" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="4" /> 

            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="LastName" Grid.Row="1" Margin="4" /> 
            <TextBox x:Name="LName" Text="{Binding LastName, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="4" /> 

            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Age" Grid.Row="2" Margin="4" /> 
            <TextBox x:Name="Age" Text="{Binding Age, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="4" /> 

            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Email" Grid.Row="3" Margin="4" /> 
            <TextBox x:Name="Email" Text="{Binding Email, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="4" /> 

            <dataInput:ValidationSummary Margin="4" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" /> 


        </Grid> 



    </Grid> 
</UserControl>
```

code of control ...

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl 
    { 
        private PersonServiceClient Client; 
        private EndpointAddress AddressService = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://localhost:3589/PersonService.svc")); 

        public MainPage() 
        { 
            InitializeComponent(); 

            Client = new PersonServiceClient(new BasicHttpBinding(), AddressService); 
            Client.GetPersonsAsync(); 
            Client.GetPersonsCompleted += new EventHandler<GetPersonsCompletedEventArgs>(Client_GetPersonsCompleted); 
        } 

        void Client_GetPersonsCompleted(object sender, GetPersonsCompletedEventArgs e) 
        { 
            ObservableCollection<Person> PersonItems = e.Result; 
            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = PersonItems;             
        } 

        private void dataGrid1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) 
        { 
            DataContext = e.AddedItems[0]; 
        } 
    }
```